# Regexp not selecting link value

Tags: php, html, regex

I want to get the value of a link that has a specific classname.

Here is my regexp:

```
<a.*?\sclass="fullname">(.*?)</a>
```

Here is a link with `class="fullname"` that *should* match:

`<a href="/abc/show?fp=eyJmaXJzdCI6IiIsImxhc3QiOiJKb2huIiwic3RyZWV0IjoiMTI3IENhcmx0b24gQXZlIiwiY2l0eSI6IkJyb29rbHluIiwic3RhdGUiOiJOWSIsInBob25lIjoiNzE4LTYyNS0wNzU4IiwiemlwIjoiMTEyMDUifQ%3D%3D&amp;form=sbn" data-analytics='{"click_id":1649,"adclick":false}' class="fullname">C John</a>`

And here is a link with `class="abc"` that should *not* match:

`<a href="/abc/show?fp=eyJmaXJzdCI6IiIsImxhc3QiOiJKb2huIiwic3RyZWV0IjoiMTI3IENhcmx0b24gQXZlIiwiY2l0eSI6IkJyb29rbHluIiwic3RhdGUiOiJOWSIsInBob25lIjoiNzE4LTYyNS0wNzU4IiwiemlwIjoiMTEyMDUifQ%3D%3D&amp;form=sbn" data-analytics='{"click_id":1649,"adclick":false}' class="abc">C John</a>`

In this case, the regexp must match the first link, but this is not working.

Comment: works, https://regex101.com/r/fK2mF3/2

Comment: [Don't try to parse HTML with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), SimpleHTMLDom will do a much better job

Comment: Per @AvinashRaj's comment, the pattern works judging by my check with Debuggex too.

Comment: Looks ok, you might have a too old PHP version which does not implement all of RE or similar problem? Try to test with simpler patterns first.